# SAS Case Statement - if this, then that . else leave as is

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas, case

I have a column with some unwanted data "XX" and want to set them as 0. Otherwise, keep the column's data as it is. Something similar to if columnA = "XX" then 0 Else columnA. I tried doing this using a proc SQL SAS step, but that did not work. So looking for the most efficient way of doing using SAS SQL. Thanks for any help.

```
if columnA = "XX" then 0 
Else columnA
End as columnA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CASE statement in SQL.

```
Case when columnA='XX' then '0'
     else columnA 
end as ColumnA_New
```

original code:
    Case when columnA='XX' then 0
         else columnA 
    end as ColumnA

Comment: I tried that in SAS. And I got this error.
A CASE expression has no ELSE clause. Cases not accounted for by the WHEN clauses will result in a missing value for the CASE 
      expression.

Comment: Not with the code I posted, it gives a type mismatch error because of the lack of quotes and if that is fixed you get a warning about using the same name but not the error indicated so your code is wrong somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the help.This might also have to do with the codes being inside a SAS macro. I am going to use the case statement in Teradata. Thanks again.

Comment: Macro won't be an issue, but if you're using SQL Pass through then that would be the issue. The SQL then needs to be Teradata SQL not SAS SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in proc sql:

```
proc sql;
    select (case when columnA = 'xx' then '0' else columnA end) as columnA
    from t;
```

Note that the `0` is a string in this expression.  `columnA` appears to be a string (based on the comparison).  A `case` expression returns a value with a specified type -- and in this case, it should be a string.

Comment: Not sure why you included the parentheses around the CASE statement but they shouldn't cause any trouble.

Comment: @tom . . . I always put parentheses around expressions, including `case` expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I still get the SAS error message "A CASE expression has no ELSE clause. Cases not accounted for by the WHEN clauses will result in a missing value for the CASE expression." This might also have to do with the codes being inside a SAS macro. I am going to use the case statement in Teradata. Thanks again.

Comment: @BlueBob . . . That should be a warning, not an error, but you can always add an explicit `else null` -- although that is not required in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Both prior solutions work and are fine. Indeed, the solution was asked in **proc sql**, yet I find data step-approach seems more simple. Posting it here for completeness sake.

```
/*Generate sample data*/
data begin; 
  input value @@; 
  cards; 
1 2  3  2.5 1.7 3 34 33 33 33.7 34 34
  ; run;

/*replace value=33 with zeros*/
data wanted; 
  set begin; 
    if value = 33 then value=0; 
run;
```